Are US banks allowed to invest money that is currently being transferred via electronic funds transfer?
I am moving some money between 2 US banks via ACH (Automated Clearing House) and it's taking almost 1 week ("Hold Placed on Electronic Deposit added"). This makes me wonder: are US banks allowed to invest money that is currently being transferred via electronic funds transfer?

Money is fungible. I don't know how you would identify that the money being invested is the same money that's being transfered.

@Barmar Why not? Say the bank receives $1 million it's required to hold as cash, so tonight, the books must show $1 million more in cash. If the bank's cash position is unchanged and has $1 million more in bonds, then that's illegal. Banks also have to segregate customer and corporate funds. Lawyers do the same thing, client funds are held in a separate account.

@user71659, the capacity in which lawyers hold client money, is not generally the same as the capacity in which banks hold depositor money. Indeed most lawyers hold client money by depositing it all at a bank! The major role of a bank is to use depositor money as a reserve for issuing loans.

@user71659 The transfer would have to be a large fraction of the bank's total assets to be able to make such a determination. Since that's practically never the case, I didn't consider it.


money that is currently being transferred via electronic funds transfer

It's important to understand that money doesn't have to change hands during a bank transfer.
Instead, the role a clearing-house performs is to coordinate a "cross-book accounting entry" - an accounting transaction that affects the accounting books of more than one institution.
When you ask can they "invest the money", you're basically talking about their money.
Their books don't record what money of yours they hold for you. It records their money, and it also records how much money they owe you (not hold for you).
There are rules about what kinds of risks banks can take with their own money, or proportionally how much cash they must hold as reserves to meet demands from creditors (such as depositors).
However, there are no general rules that require them to forgo sensible investment of their own money.

Yes
All banks do this all the time.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
